# Frame buffer not rendering depth into depth texture

Tags: c++, opengl

So, i have this assignment about double pass rendering to compute shadows and I am trying to store the depth value of each of the objects of a scene and rendering them as a texture in another object.

I am using OpenGL, I don't really know where the error could be, but when analyzing a capture with RenderDoc, it says that the FBO (FrameBufferObject) is unused and also interprets what should be my 1st pass, a depth only pass, as a color pass.

```
/*-This is how I create the FBO and the texture to render the depth-*/

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

// Create texture for Depth image (first pass)
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);

// Give pixel data to opengl
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);


// WITH PCF for anti-aliasing shadow edges 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);



glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D,     
depthTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
/*---------------------------END------------------------------------*/

/*---This is how I render all the objects (1st and second pass)-----*/
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

cube.FirstPass(light.getPos());
plane.FirstPass(light.getPos());
cone1.FirstPass(light.getPos());
cone2.FirstPass(light.getPos());

glFlush();
glFinish();

glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

cube.display(&cam, light.getPos());
plane.display(&cam, light.getPos());
viewport.display(&cam, light.getPos());
cone1.display(&cam, light.getPos());
cone2.display(&cam, light.getPos());
/*---------------------------END------------------------------------*/

/*---------This is how I do First Pass---------*/
//Here goes first pass
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sceneManager.getFBO());

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    

glUseProgram(DepthPass.shader);

glm::mat4 mtx = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), 1024.0f / 1024.0f,          5.0f, 40.0f);

DepthPass.setMat("M", mtx * glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)) *             
getModelToWorld());

glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Draw
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, ModelVertices.size());


glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
/*---------------------------END------------------------------------*/

/*--This is what I pass to the shader that shows the depth texture--*/
DepthPass.setFloat("near", 5.0f);
DepthPass.setFloat("far", 40.0);

DepthPass.setInt("IsViewport", 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

//GetDepthTexture() returns a handle of the texture created before

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sceneManager.GetDepthTexture());
std::string textureName = "depthTexture";
DepthPass.setInt(textureName.c_str(), sceneManager.GetDepthTexture());

/*---------------------------END------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: You've to clear the depth buffer of the framebuffer. First bind the framebuffer `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, *(sceneManager.getFBO()));`, then clear the depth buffer `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: Does `getFBO()` return a pointer to what?

Comment: @Ripi2 to the FBO handler I create with                                
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

Comment: OGL uses `FBO` as a number, not a pointer. You pass `&FBO` because OGL will write the number in it. I guess your `sceneManager` stores FBO (not &FBO). So, try `*(scene...)` without `*`

Comment: @Ripi2 I tried but I get the same result, black texture and unused FBO

Comment: Next check is your fragment shader.

Comment: @Ripi2 my vertex shader only transforms positions in world space to light space and the fragment is an empty main function

Comment: Empty? Then, when is the FBO written?

Comment: @Ripi2 Of course the fragment shader is empty. Only the depth is set to the depth buffer. This is perfect valid.

Comment: @Loki Did you finally clear the depth buffer of the framebuffer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, I am editing the post with the recommendations I get but don´t make it work